# Typescript Generics When Dealing with Disparate Third-Party Namespaces (firebase-admin vs firebase client)

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, typescript-generics

tldr; Is there a better/simpler way of using Typescript generics and conditional types than what I have below, given my use case with Firebase admin and client libraries?

In my Firebase project I have code that I share between admin functions and a javascript client (Angular app.) Mostly this is just interfaces, types and enums, but there are certain situations where it's really convenient to share functional code. This is made somewhat difficult by the fact that Firebase's Node admin types (the firebase-admin package) and its client javascript types (the firebase package) seem to be entirely separate -- the types don't seem to share any sort of common root.

I've managed to overcome this in a kind of janky way, using typescript generics and conditionals. Example:

```
// import types only so nobody complains when compiling...
import type { firestore } from 'firebase-admin';
import type firebase from 'firebase/app';

// my interfaces for the shape of the Firestore docs
import {
  IUserDoc,
  // etc...
} from './firestore-doc-interfaces';

// conditional types...
type Firestore<F> = F extends firestore.Firestore
  ? firestore.Firestore
  : firebase.firestore.Firestore;
type C<F, T> = F extends firestore.Firestore
  ? firestore.CollectionReference<T>
  : firebase.firestore.CollectionReference<T>;
type D<F, T> = F extends firestore.Firestore
  ? firestore.DocumentReference<T>
  : firebase.firestore.DocumentReference<T>;

export abstract class AbstractFirestoreRefs<F> {
  abstract store: Firestore<F>;

  // janky return "as" (needed in every method)
  usersCollection(): C<F, IUserDoc> {
    return this.store.collection('users') as C<F, IUserDoc>;
  }
  userDoc(uid: string): D<F, IUserDoc> {
    return this.usersCollection().doc(uid) as D<F, IUserDoc>;
  }
}
```

Admin implementation:

```
import { AbstractFirestoreRefs } from '../shared-api';
import { firestore } from 'firebase-admin';
export class FirestoreRefs extends AbstractFirestoreRefs<firestore.Firestore> {
  get store(): firestore.Firestore {
    //returns the firestore.Firestore instance
  }
}
```

Client implementation:

```
import { AbstractFirestoreRefs } from '../../shared-api';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirestoreRefsService extends AbstractFirestoreRefs<firebase.firestore.Firestore> {
  
  get store(): firebase.firestore.Firestore {
    // returns the firebase.firestore.Firestore instance
  }
}
```

This works (i.e. my linter likes it, it compiles, and it actually works) on both admin and client. But it seems a bit flaky and verbose. In particular the repetitive `return ... as ...` syntax, which I can't get around.

There are two benefits to making an abstract base class that can be shared between Node and the client, rather than having one class for admin and a (more or less) duplicate one for the client:

- The document paths remain consistent. Important if you have lots of collections.
- The generic `T` typings remain consistent.  These give the type information for my business logic (e.g. `IUserDoc`.) Both the admin and client Firebase libraries have (optionally) strong typings: You will get an error if you try  to set a `DocumentReference<IDog>` with the wrong shape. This is pretty indispensable for a non-trivial database with lots of different document shapes.

All the rest of the generic types (`F`, `C` and `D`) just there to discriminate between the admin and client flavors of `Firestore`, `CollectionReference` and `DocumentReference`.

So two questions:

1. Am I missing something about the Firebase libraries that would make this easier? That is, some sort of base namespace?
2. Am I missing something about Typescript generics that would make it easier?

Thanks!

Comment: this is a good question. It might be worth raising this in Firebase's github issues.

Comment: @jmc42 Thanks. But since Firebase is pretty radically changing it's SDK, I think I'll hold off for a few months.

Comment: I did something similar to solve this (which agreed, is really an issue w Firebase's API design).  I just ended up with functions that took `firebase.Firestore | firebase.firestore.Firestore`